# Distance value lost after submit or search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

The distance drop down value is lost after you perform a **Search** or you look at a job based on the search results.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open jobs and set some search filters such as "Allows Remote"
2. Specify the distance, say 100 miles
3. Click the **Search** button
4. Now look at the results and hover over the location drop down, notice the distance drop down is reset back to 20 miles

This same issue happens when you click into a job and come back to the search results.  The distance in miles is reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only happens when you select a distance without actually entering a location, in which case the distance selection is meaningless and just gets ignored.

Note that it works as expected when a location is entered: the distance selection is preserved both in the drop-down and when returning to search results.

[image]